# Get element by attribute value variables (xpath)

Tags: xpath

This works:

```
$test: img[@data-src="https://www.google.com/"]
```

but with variable?

```
# fail!
img[@data-src={$og_image}]
```

Comment: @Slowaways Probably: `img[@data-src="{$og_image}"]` ?

Comment: This is not duplicated!

Comment: `img[@data-src="{$og_image}"]` this don't work